# Is the frequency of Korotkoff beats equal to the pulse rate?

Tags: blood, blood-pressure

When measuring blood pressure using a sphygmomanometer (BP cuff), you listen for Korotkoff sounds caused by turbulent blood flow through the artery. They appear as beating noises. Is this beating noise correlated with the pulse? Is the frequency the same?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly mentioned, Korotkoff sounds are caused by a turbulent flow wave, going through the artery - which, by definition, occurs when the heart muscle contracts. So yes, what you hear is the same as what you would feel when taking a pulse.

**Additional note: in some cases peripheral pulse might not represent the exact heart beat (see [pulse deficit](https://study.com/academy/lesson/pulse-deficit-definition-causes.html))*